# Passing a value retrieved from a database to another page using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass a value that I have received from my database to another php page to use within another SQL statement.
I have tried using sessions and also passing using the $_POST method on the other page but have had no luck.

Here is a snippet of my code looping through to display all records:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<td>
          <img src='.'"'.$row['image'].'"'.'><br/>
          <form method="post" action="edit-record.php">
          <input type="text" name="imgID" value='.'"'.$row['id'].'"'.'>
          <input type="submit" value="Edit" id="edit_btn" class="admin_btn"></form>
      </td>';
}
```

The value that I need is the ID for each specific image - `$row['id']`.

When the user clicks the EDIT button, they should be redirected to another page which displays only the specific record. This is why I need the ID received passed to the next page to insert into a query statement.

I hope this made sense and any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Thanks for all of your help. I solved the problem by playing around with a few of your suggestions to pass the id via GET in the action of the form.

`<form method="post" action="edit-record.php?id='. $row['id'].'">`

No idea why that hadn't occurred to me! Thanks again.

Comment: as an alternative, you could also use a simple link anchor. `edit.php?id=<echo the id here>`. and from that just use `$_GET['id']`

Comment: How is this not working? What happens if you `print_r($_POST)` at the top of edit_record.php?

Comment: did you make sure that there is a value within $row['id'] ?

Comment: The 'edit item' button should really be an 'anchor tag'  where the 'href' is the url including the 'id' of the record. Style it to look like a 'button' using css. It sends you to the 'edit item' page and the 'id' is in the '$_GET' array.

Comment: You don't need to "escape" double-quotes like that, you can just put them inside the single quotes like a regular character, can you show how do you retrive `POST` values in `edit-record.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<td>
              <img src="'.$row['image'].'"><br/>
              <form method="post" action="edit-record.php">
                  <input type="text" name="imgID" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                  <input type="submit" value="Edit" id="edit_btn" class="admin_btn">
              </form>
          </td>';
}
```

in edit-record.php...

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['imgID'];
?>
```

There is no reason your code technically wouldn't work but instead you could just eliminate the form and use a simple link...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<td>
              <img src="'.$row['image'].'"><br/>
              <a href="edit-record.php?id='.$row['id'].'">edit</a>
          </td>';
}
```

and in edit-record.php...

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

4 Ways to do this...

1) Use a cookie
2) Use a session (which by default uses a cookie but in a different way)
3) Use cURL
4) add it to the GET parameters... ie. somepage.com/page.php?id=1

Answer (score 0):

Strange concatenation

```
 <input type="text" name="imgID" value="'.$row['id'].'">
```

Sure you select id on the mysql query???

If you make

```
  echo $_POST['imgID'];
```

what is the result???

You can pass the id via get in the action form:

```
 <form method="post" action="edit-record.php?id='. $row['id'].' ">
```

On the other page you recive the form in $_POST and the id in $_GET['id']

Answer (score 0):

~Aha, I think the problem is your quotes. Single quotes don't allow variables to be interpreted.~

Nevermind, thats not your problem, but I already wrote it out, so I'll leave it. Look how much cleaner those quotes are :)

Switch up your quotes like so:

```
echo "<td>
          <img src='{$row['image']}'><br/>
          <form method='post' action='edit-record.php'>
          <input type='text' name='imgID' value='{$row['id']'}'>
          <input type='submit' value='Edit' id='edit_btn' class='admin_btn'></form>
      </td>";
```

Need curly braces around array element (e.g `{$row['id']}`)